# Discord.py rewrite bot won't change my nickname

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I've been learning Python 3.8 by building a Discord bot for my small server of friends. I want my friends to be able to change my nickname, but Discord doesn't seem to allow that unless I give everyone the same rank.

My idea was to give my bot the highest role and let them use a bot command to change my nickname (which would be the second-highest role), but I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/cqqlguy/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 333, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/cqqlguy/CQQLBOT/CQQLBOT.py", line 516, in on_message
    await cqqluser.edit(nick = newnick)
  File "/home/cqqlguy/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/member.py", line 601, in edit
    await http.edit_member(guild_id, self.id, reason=reason, **payload)
  File "/home/cqqlguy/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 241, in request
    raise Forbidden(r, data)
discord.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions
```

The relevant code looks like this:

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    lowermess = message.content
    dMess = lowermess.lower()

    if dMess.startswith("$changenick "):
            newnick = lowermess.split(" ", 1)[1] #whatever the user enters after the command
            changeuser = guild.get_member(id) #id would be my user ID
            await changeuser.edit(nick = newnick)
```

This seems to work on users that aren't me, but the bot has been given a higher role than everyone so I'm not sure why it's not changing it for me.

Comment: The error pretty much speaks for itself... If you're the owner there's no one higher in the hierarchy than you, the bot won't be able to change your nick.

Comment: Even if the bot's role is higher than mine and has "Administrator" granted to them?

Comment: @LarryPancake if the bot is Administrator it should be able to imo.
In my Bot, I built a rolemenu and the bot can use .edit on me to add or remove roles

Did you check that your bot has the permission "Manage nicknames" ?

Comment: Bot is Admin, has the "Manage Nicknames" slider, and is top role of my server. I'm not sure if there's a better way to share screenshots on StackOverflow, but here's screenshots from my discord roles page https://imgur.com/a/c5pOzi7

Comment: There is no way to change the owner's nickname at all, thats just how discord works. The way we fixed that in my friends server is by making an alt the owner, then your main account is no longer the owner of the server and you're free to do whatever you want with your nick :D

Comment: @FierySpectreI guess that solves it. Not the answer I'd hoped for, but I appreciate the info and workaround.

Comment: @FierySpectre Please write an answer saying that and try to find a source for what you are saying so the question can be closed

Comment: @NathanMarotte I can't seem to find any mention of it in the docs, nor in the discord.py docs nor in the official discord developer docs. so I'm afraid i cant give a source. Hence I cant really build a proper answer...